# How to add slightly similar content with regular expressions (regex)?

Tags: regex, dreamweaver, replace

I'm using Dreamweaver on a file that has about 30 instances the following:

```
'portfolio_bg' =>'#555555',
'portfolio_font'=>'#ffffff',
```

But, for each instance the hex codes are different.  I want to add the following two lines underneath the above:

```
'product_bg' =>'#555555',
'product_font'=>'#ffffff',
```

where the hex codes in my two product lines will match the hex codes of the portfolio lines above it.

How do I accomplish his using regular expressions in Dreamweaver's Find and Replace?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it always specifically "portfolio" and "product", or can these be arbitrary words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me in EditPad Pro; it should work in Dreamweaver too.

Find:

```
'portfolio_bg'\s*=>\s*'(#[0-9A-Fa-f]+)',(\s+)'portfolio_font'\s*=>\s*'(#[0-9A-Fa-f]+)',\s*
```

Replace:

```
$&$2'product_bg' =>'$1',$2'product_font'=>'$3',$2
```

**EDIT:** corrected replacement string to use `$&` instead of `$0`.

Comment: Hi Alan, thanks.  Two things happened with your code.  First, it replaced the portfolio instances instead of adding the product instances after them.  Second, it added a lines with only "$0" on them.

Comment: My bad.  Dreamweaver uses JavaScript syntax, so you have to use `$&` instead of `$0`.

Answer (score 0):

For the first line, use the following RegEx replacement:

Find:

```
'portfolio_bg'[ \t]*=>[ \t]*'(#[0-9]{6})',
```

Replace:

```
'portfolio_bg' =>'\1',\n'product_bg' =>'\1',
```

For the second line,, use the following RegEx replacement:

Find:

```
'portfolio_font'[ \t]*=>[ \t]*'(#[0-9a-f]{6})',
```

Replace:

```
'portfolio_font' =>'\1',\n'product_font' =>'\1',
```

Comment: POSIX "character classes" like `[:blank:]` are not meant to be used on their own.  You have to put them inside another set of square brackets (what POSIX calls a *bracket expression* and everyone else calls a *character class*).  But I'm pretty sure Dreamweaver's regex flavor doesn't support those things anyway.

Comment: I used Perl-style RegEx.  Do you know which flavour is used by Dreamweaver?